# Oracle group by takes lot of time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select query which takes lot of time:

```
select  user_id, variable, round(AVG(v_Score),1) v_score 
     from TEST_1M_SCORE_V1 where clock between 1 and 12 group by user_id, variable
```

This table - `TEST_1M_SCORE_V1` has 260,000,000 rows.

Is there any other way of writing group by clause so it works faster?

Table definition:

```
Name          Null Type          
------------- ---- ------------- 
USER_ID             NUMBER        
CLOCK               NUMBER        
VARIABLE           VARCHAR2(255) 
V_SCORE            NUMBER
```

Comment: You can try an index on `clock`, if that condition is highly selective.

Comment: Show the table definition including indexes.A composed index on `clock, user_id,variable` would be useful

Comment: added table definition.

Comment: @dang you already have an index on `clock` or a composite index on `clock, user_id, variable`?

Comment: @DStanley - I have index on clock.

Comment: How much is "a lot of time"?  What would an acceptable amount of time be?

Comment: @Mihai Sorry, that comment should have been directed at the OP, not you.

Comment: Maybe a parallel hint:  select /*+ PARALLEL(16)*/  user_id, variable, round(AVG(v_Score),1) v_score 
     from TEST_1M_SCORE_V1 where clock between 1 and 12 group by user_id, variable   You might also try an index on user_id alone as it may be more selective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is two answers, not one, depending on the data.  This is your query:

```
select user_id, variable, round(AVG(v_Score), 1) as v_score 
from TEST_1M_SCORE_V1
where clock between 1 and 12
group by user_id, variable;
```

Option 1 is that relatively few rows satisfy the `where` condition -- where "relatively few" is definitely not more than a handful of percent.  In this case, an index on `TEST_1M_SCORE_V1(clock)` would be useful.  You can extend this to `TEST_1M_SCORE_V1(clock, user_id, variable, score)`, for a covering index.  Oracle will need to do all the work for the `group by`, but just on less data.

Option 2 is when more rows satisfy the `where` condition.  In this case, you want Oracle to do a full index scan for the `group by`.  The problem is that `where` clause.  One approach is to incorporate it into the index, using a function-based index.  However, that is highly specific (it works for 1 and 12 but not 1 and 11).

Instead, write the query as:

```
select user_id, variable,
       round(AVG(case when clock between 1 and 12 then v_Score end), 1) as v_score 
from TEST_1M_SCORE_V1
group by user_id, variable
having sum(case when clock between 1 and 12 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

(The `having` clause may not be necessary, depending on how much you care about `user_id`/`variable` combos where the `avg()` will be `NULL`.)

This query is equivalent to the original.  It seems to be doing more work, but that work is highly optimized for an index scan on: `TEST_1M_SCORE_V1(user_id, variable, clock, v_score)`.  The idea is that Oracle can read the index, in order, doing the `group by` and calculations at the same time.  It never needs to look up data in the original data set and it never needs to process the `group by` using a hash- or sort-based algorithm.